# Javascript http post into form

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`var dataToSend = "randomStuff";`

I want `dataToSend` to be send via POST into

`<textarea class="form-control" name="list" rows="1" id="comment"></textarea>`

this specific textarea is not local, its a random html page.

How do I do that?
I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work. Can someone bring me onto the right path? (Without jquery if possible, but appreciate any suggestions,...)

Thank you.

Comment: It´s simply not possible. You´ll need some actual code (probably php or javascript) on the 'target page' to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of these makes sense (Which is probably why it didn't work). My suggestions is that you change your question to ask what you need done, not how you want it done (See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That isn't how POSTing works.

When you make an HTTP request you can include data in in various ways (the query string on the URL, the body of the request, cookies, custom HTTP headers, etc). When people talk about POSTing data, they usually mean the body of the request.

The data is sent to the HTTP server that the URL points to.

It is the responsibility of the server (or possibly JavaScript embedded in the document returned by the server) to do something with that data.

It could read data from the request and put it in then HTML document it responds with. That technique could be used to set a default value for a textarea.

The important point is that it is the responsibility of the site providing the textarea.

**There is no way for code on a website to populate the value of a textarea on an arbitrary third party site.**

---

It is, however, possible to make a POST request to the end point that the form containing the textarea points to.

The simplest way is to make a form with the same `action` and a form control with the same name (`list`).

That form could be populated and submitted by JavaScript since it is on the same page.